# Processes in uninterruptible sleep when the server is not responding

Tags: ssh, mount, kill, sshfs

I'm using sshfs to mount and interact with directories and files located on a remote server. The command I'm using is:

```
sshfs -o follow_symlinks host:dir mountpoint -o reconnect
```

Sometimes, after a period of inactivity, when I wake up the computer from the suspended mode, processes that use a resource on the remote server do not respond anymore.
[image]
It mainly happens for the Nautilus (Files) and can happen for Okular if an opened PDF file is located on the remote server.

Trying to kill those processes with `kill -9` does not work. For example, when the Nautilus doesn't respond, here are the command I'm using to try to kill the process:

```
toto:~/.ssh$ ps aux | grep nautilus
toto   21435  0.4  0.3 1440760 123276 ?      Sl   09:32   1:48 /usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service
toto   96139  0.0  0.0   9216  2428 pts/4    S+   15:44   0:00 grep --color=auto nautilus
toto:~/.ssh$ kill -9 21435
```

I've learned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work) this is because they are in *uninterruptible sleep*. From [this other discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14143/what-is-a-better-way-to-deal-with-server-disconnects-of-sshfs-mounts), I thought a solution was to use `-o reconnect` as parameter for sshfs. Unfortunately, I still get apps that do not respond after the computer wakes up.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with `ServerAliveInterval` with `ServerAliveCountMax` and/or `ClientAliveInterval`

> ServerAliveInterval seems to be the most common strategy to keep a connection alive and to prevent the broken pipe problem.

[What do options `ServerAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveInterval` in sshd_config do exactly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3027/515538)

**In shell**:

`sshfs -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o follow_symlinks host:dir mountpoint -o reconnect`

> The client will wait idle for 60 seconds (ServerAliveInterval time) and, send a "no-op null packet" to the server and expect a response. If no response comes, then it will keep trying the above process till 3 (ServerAliveCountMax) times (180 seconds). If the server still doesn't respond, then the client disconnects the ssh connection.

`ClientAliveCountMax`

> `ClientAliveCountMax` on the server side might also help. This is the
> limit of how long a client are allowed to stay unresponsive before
> being disconnected. The default value is 3, as in three
> ClientAliveInterval.

**Config `~/.ssh/config`**

```
Host myhostshortcut
     HostName myhost.com
     User barthelemy
     ServerAliveInterval 60
     ServerAliveCountMax 10
```

**Kill the parent process**

Kill the parent process, instead of trying to kill the unresponsive process directly.

Find the parent process id `ppid` of the unresponsive process use

`ps -ef`

In this case, the parent process of the unresponsive process is the one created by the `sshfs` command. The following command will help to find it in the list of running processes.

`ps -ef | grep sshfs`

If you have the `ppid`, use the `kill` command with the `pid`.

`kill -9 1268`

Kill the parent process should terminate the child process as well.

Comment: I got the problem again. It is maybe from a server to which I didn't configure ServerAliveInterval yet. I managed to kill the parent process by looking for the ppid with `ps -ef | grep sshfs`. I think it could be nice to add it to your answer. It takes me a little time to understand that the "parent" process was the one generated by the sshfs command. I'll make a few more tests with the ServerAliveInterval to see if the problem persists or not.

Comment: @TVG | One solution is to set up a script or a `system service` that automatically reconnects the SSHFS mount when the client wakes up from sleep. Use tools like `systemd (system service)` or creating a custom script that detects the client's `sleep/wake events` and triggers the reconnection process.

Comment: Create a service | https://linuxhandbook.com/create-systemd-services/ | https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I want to add a `system service`. Let's see first if `ServerAliveInterval` solved the problem.